# Searching for an email in all Exchange 2007 mails boxs

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have an email address and need a power shell command to search all email boxes in the company to find all emails relating to this.

what would be the best command to use iv been looking around but can seem to fine a close enough answer.

I'm pretty new to using power shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by reading through the Help on Export-Mailbox:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998579(v=EXCHG.80).aspx

The examples there shoud get you started. If you can't get that to work, you can come back and have examples of wha't you've tried as a starting point.